# Как вывести сложенное итоговое значение в строку <p> из базы данных?

Tags: php, mysql

### Как вывести одно максимальное значение в строку

из базы данных?

Есть код `<?php foreach ($db->query('SELECT * FROM singles')->fetchAll() as $article) { ?>`  **здесь уже строка где выводится кол-во просмотров** `<p><?php echo $article['views'] ?></p> <?php } ?>`  и он выдаёт много чисел в ряд (Скриншот ниже)

---

**Как сделать чтобы итоговую *сложенную* сумму просмотров в один ряд** `<p>`?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы результат запроса сложите в переменную. Дальше уже этой переменной оперируйте с помощью `foreach`. Что это даст? А всё просто. Вы **до** цикла сможете посчитать количество записей или взять конкретное значение у результата. И так же **вне** цикла уже сможете оперировать этим значением

```
$articles = $db->query('SELECT * FROM singles')->fetchAll();
$totalViewsCount = array_reduce(array_column($articles, 'views'), function($acc, $item) {
    return $acc += $item;
}, 0);
```

По идее в `$totalViewsCount` должно быть то самое число, которое надо вывести один раз после цикла или до.

Comment: Как это сделать?)

Comment: @ytviga как-то так наверное ↑↑↑